# How can i get data from database based on the session?

Tags: php, html, session

I have a login script where the redirect page is made based on the role of the user so if it is admin it goes to admin.php and if its tester it goes to tester.php so in the first session the user role is given and in my other session called loggedin i give the username. in my database i have a couple more things from the user profile and what i want is the firstname and the lastname shown when the user logged in.

Here you can see my verification script.

```
<?php
            session_start();
            $mysqli=new MySQLi("localhost", "root", "root", "portfolio");
            $role="";

            $username=filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $password=filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

            if($query=$mysqli->prepare("SELECT `role` FROM members WHERE username=? AND password=?"))
            {
            $query->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
            $query->execute();
            $query->bind_result($role);
            $query->fetch();
            }
            else
            {
            echo "Errors in the Query. ".$mysqli->error;
            die();
            }

            if($role!="")
            {
                $_SESSION['ingelogt']=$username;
                $_SESSION['user_role']=$role;
                $location="$role.php"; // If role is admin this will be admin.php, if student this will be student.php and more.
                header("location: $location"); // Redirect to the respective pages.
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Invalid password, username combination";
            }
            ?>
```

And here is the page where the admin will be redirected when he is succesfuly loggedin

```
<?php
            session_start();
            if(!isset($_SESSION['ingelogt']))
            {
                header("location: index.php"); // The user is not logged in. Redirect him to the login page.
            }

            $page_role="admin"; // This must be admin for admin.php and student for student.php and similar

            $role=$_SESSION['user_role'];

            if($role!=$page_role) // If student come to admin page by mistake or admin to student and similar
            {
                echo "You are not supposed to be here.";
                die();
            }

            $dom = new DOMDocument();
            libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
            $dom->loadHTMLFile("admin.html");
            libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

            if($_SESSION['user_role']) {
                $oUl = $dom->getElementById('navUl');
                    $oList = $dom->createElement('li');

                        $oLink = $dom->createElement('a');
                        $oLink->setAttribute('href','logout.php');

                            $oI = $dom->createElement('i');
                            $oI->setAttribute('class','icon-logout');

                            $oLink->appendChild($oI);

                        $oList->appendChild($oLink);

                    $oUl->appendChild($oList);
            }

            echo $dom->saveHTML();
            ?>
```

So what i want is when the user is logged in that his firstname and lastname will be shown.
I hope someone can help me

The updated files
the verification.php

```
<?php
                session_start();
                // Making a connection with the database.
                $mysqli=new MySQLi("localhost", "root", "root", "portfolio"); 
                $role=""; 

                // Declaring the username and password input.
                $username=filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
                $password=filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 

                // If role from members where username and password from inputs exicts in database bind parameters.
                // If given parameters not excists in database die
                if($query=$mysqli->prepare("SELECT `id`,`role` FROM members WHERE username=? AND password=?")) {
                    $query->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);                                         
                    $query->execute();                                                                
                    $query->bind_result($id, $role);
                    $query->fetch();
                } else {                                                                                    
                    echo "Errors in the Query. ".$mysqli->error;                                            
                    die();
                }

                // If $role is filled make session for username to check if logged in and session role for redirect page.
                // If $role and $username is not filled invalid password, username combination.
                if($role!="") {                                                                           
                    $_SESSION['ingelogt']=$username;                                                        
                    $_SESSION['user_role']=$role;       
                    $_SESSION['user_id']=$id;                                           
                    $location="$role.php";                                                                  
                    header("location: $location");                                                          
                } else {                                                                                   
                    echo "Invalid password, username combination";                                          
                }
            ?>
```

and the admin.php

```
                <?php
                session_start();
                // If session is not ingelogt lead back to index.php.
                if(!isset($_SESSION['ingelogt'])) {
                    header("location: index.php"); 
                }

                // The role that has access to this page.
                $page_role="admin"; 
                $role=$_SESSION['user_role'];
                // If a user with a different role visits wrong page.
                if($role!=$page_role)
                {
                    echo "You are not supposed to be here.";
                    die();
                }

                // Start new DOMDocument and load html file.
                $dom = new DOMDocument();
                libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
                $dom->loadHTMLFile("admin.html");
                libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

                // If user is logged in add logg out icon in the menu.
                if($_SESSION['ingelogt']) {
                    $oUl = $dom->getElementById('navUl');
                        $oList = $dom->createElement('li');

                            $oLink = $dom->createElement('a');
                            $oLink->setAttribute('href','logout.php');

                                $oI = $dom->createElement('i');
                                $oI->setAttribute('class','icon-logout');

                                $oLink->appendChild($oI);

                            $oList->appendChild($oLink);

                        $oUl->appendChild($oList);
                }
                // Save DOMDocument with html document.
                echo $_SESSION['user_id'];
                echo $dom->saveHTML();
            ?>
```

Comment: Dose your Member Table have firstname and lastname ?

Comment: Yes my members tabel contains the following.
id, firstname, lastname, username, password and role

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want, is to keep the user id in `$_SESSION`, so modify your query as such:

```
 SELECT `id`,`role` FROM members WHERE username=? AND password=?
```

Then, the same way you have added `$role`, just add `$id`,

```
 $_SESSION['userID'] = $id;
```

Then in the next page, you can use `$_SESSION['userID']` to query for the information you need.

As a sidenote, consider using `password_hash()` so that your passwords are not stored in the DB as plaintext.

Comment: Thanks alot :) And yes I will use the pasword_hash() but for now i was just doing some other things.

Comment: For some reason when i do echo $_SESSION['user_role']; it shows admin but when i echo $_SESSION['userID']; it gives Notice: Undefined index: user_id in C:\dev\www\admin.php on line 40 but i have done what you said

Comment: @KingMike: Are you using userID or user_ID when storing/retrieving the ID from SESSION? Your sample shows userID; but, the error message says user_ID.

Comment: im using user_id now :P but i still get Notice: Undefined index: user_id in C:\dev\www\admin.php on line 40

Comment: my example relied on setting `$SESSION['userID']` on log in, so it should be set once you have logged in, if you set it up on the previous page.

Comment: I have updated the scripts so you can check what im doing wrong perhaps? @serakfalcon

Answer (score 0):

You could get the firstname & lastname from db and store is SESSION:

```
<?php
            session_start();
            $mysqli=new MySQLi("localhost", "root", "root", "portfolio");
            $role="";

            // add lastname & firstname
            $lastname="";
            $firstname="";

            $username=filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $password=filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

            // get lastname & first name with select
            if($query=$mysqli->prepare("SELECT `role`,`firstname`,`lastname` FROM members WHERE username=? AND password=?"))
            {
            $query->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
            $query->execute();
            $query->bind_result($role,$firstname, $lastname);
            $query->fetch();
            }
            else
            {
            echo "Errors in the Query. ".$mysqli->error;
            die();
            }

            if($role!="")
            {
                $_SESSION['ingelogt']=$username;
                $_SESSION['user_role']=$role;

                // save to session
                $_SESSION['user_lastname']=$lastname;
                $_SESSION['user_firstname']=$firstname;

                $location="$role.php"; // If role is admin this will be admin.php, if student this will be student.php and more.
                header("location: $location"); // Redirect to the respective pages.
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Invalid password, username combination";
            }
?>
```

Then on the admin page, pull the name from SESSION and put on page where desired.

Answer (score 0):

Here,You just need one more session variable to STORE user's Fist  and last name.

Change SELECT Query ;

```
"SELECT `role`,'firstname','lastname' FROM members WHERE username=? AND password=?"
```

Then If query returns any raw, ie. for valid user.

store that values in Session and use that in all other page to show first name and last name then after.